# Select an variable using multi variables

Tags: c#, variables

I have a lot of `Int32` variables that I wanted to select which `int` I want to check.
Is it possible to make this line and select an variable using multi variables?

```
Int32 redleft0 = 0; 
Int32 redleft1 = 0; 
Int32 redleft2 = 0; 
Int32 redleft3 = 0; 
Int32 redleft4 = 0; 
Int32 redleft5 = 0;
Int32 blueleft0 = 0; 
Int32 blueleft1 = 0; 
Int32 blueleft2 = 0; 
Int32 blueleft3 = 0;     
Int32 blueleft4 = 0; 
Int32 blueleft5 = 0;

redorblue = "red";    
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{ 
    String checkleftint = (redorblue + "left" + i);                   
    if (checkleftint < 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Or use byte[] / int[] since it seems that would fit what you are trying to do much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use an array - or rather two - here:

```
var red = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
var blue = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};

var arrayToUse = redorblue == "red" ? red : blue;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var value = arrayToUse[i];
    // ....
}
```

Comment: this helped not only for this problem but also helped for future problems!

Answer (score 0):

Use an Array or a Dictonary with a Key and Value so you can pull out the value using the key

Answer (score 0):

It won't work that way. Either don't use separate variables but use an array:

```
int[,] vars = new int[2,6] { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
// int[0,*] would be redleft and int[1,*] would be blueleft
```

or use a `Dictionary<string, int>`

Answer (score -1):

It's possible if you use [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
enum values { redleft0 = 0; redleft1 = 120; redleft2 = 13; }
```

By using `enum`

So what you wolud do is just:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{  
   if(i == values.redLeft0){
     ...
   }
}
```

By using `enum`, you associate a *name* you want to a *number* you want.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: Can you set the enum value?

Comment: @CR41G14: don't see any evidence in question that these values has to be set. I see that OP wants to check against them.